# What is the best strategy for tracking USER ID on a website without login system?

Tags: google-analytics

Considering a brand new feature of USER ID in Google Universal Analytics I’m wondering what is the best model to track the full customer journey for a company which sells software products and has no login system?

From which touch point (before or after software download/install) do you recommend to assign a USER ID to a user by means of Google Universal Analytics?

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Comment: I am sure this is a brilliant question, I am just not sure what continuity you would see without using an identifier- if not a user account, then perhaps a cookie. Even then, I assume you can get the same data using your own log analyzer or bug.

Answer (score 2):

To me there's two major ways to track users without a session: first a cookie and second HTTP headers.
A cookie is great if you'd like to get any request -- even images, CSS, etc. The bad thing here is that this overhead will be carried on every request about 30 to 100 times per site visited in non-SPA-sites. It's tiny but it start's bothering you when scaling up users.
The second approach is using HTTP headers -- which requires JavaScript to modify and is only applicable to SingePage-Applications (SPA).

Comment: Schultz do you have some examples, snippet code or deep explanation ?